# Unknown DOM Representation in JSON

Tags: json, api, text, slack-api

I have a Slack post that looks like this:

[What the file looks like rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di8go.png)

I queried the Slack API with the [`files.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.list) method, and with the `url_private` property of the file object, I retrieved this file:

```
{
"version":100,
"revision":206,
"root":{
    "children":[
        {
            "type":"h2",
            "text":"Header 2"
        },
        {
            "type":"p",
            "text":""
        },
        {
            "type":"p",
            "text":"\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\""
        },
        {
            "type":"p",
            "text":""
        },
        {
            "type":"p",
            "text":"Bold. Italics. Code.",
            "formats":{
                "b":[
                    0,
                    5
                ],
                "i":[
                    6,
                    20
                ],
                "code":[
                    15,
                    19
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"p",
            "text":""
        },
        {
            "type":"ol",
            "text":"Point one"
        },
        {
            "type":"ol",
            "text":"Point two"
        },
        {
            "type":"ol",
            "text":"Point three"
        },
        {
            "type":"p",
            "text":""
        },
        {
            "type":"p",
            "text":""
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Now my question is this: is this a common JSON representation of formatted text, or just something that Slack cooked up themselves? If it is common, what is it called?

EDIT: I'm aware this is a JavaScript object, and I'm aware that this is a JSON response. My confusion is related to how it handles text formatting. I'm wondering if this is a standard form of representing rich text formatting.

Comment: JSON response looks exactly like this, you may wanna parse it to a dictonary? What were you expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a JavaScript Object.

In JavaScript you can access its properties as such :

```
obj.root.children[index].type;
obj.root.children[index].text;
```

example :

```
obj.root.children[0].type; // ouputs : "h2"
```

It is obviously cooked up by Slack to represent their posts into something you can use the way you want, otherwise why provide it through an API ?